# Выход за пределы массива в задаче

Tags: java

Я новичок и уже голову сломал с этой элементарной задачей! Помогите)

```
public class MInOfTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] myArray = {1,4,3};
        int [] myArray1 = {2,5,7};
        int i=0;

        for (i=0; i<3; i++);
        {
            if (myArray[i]<myArray1[i])
                System.out.println(myArray[i]);
            else   
                System.out.println(myArray1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге выдает

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>       at MInOfTwo.main(MInOfTwo.java:10)

ссылаясь на строку с `if`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Уберите точку с запятой после цикла.

У Вас сразу после `for (i=0; i<3; i++)` стоит точка с запятой, то есть следующий за циклом блок – это **уже не тело цикла**, а просто блок, который будет выполнен **после** цикла. А после выполнения цикла `i` будет равна `3` и после этого Вы хотите получить доступ к `myArray[i]` и `myArray1[i]` и совершенно справедливо получаете `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Даже стыдно за такую глупость!